# Attribute Error module 'turtle' has no attribute 'Turtle'

Tags: python

This problem occurred to me quite recently. I have no idea what i am doing wrong due to me being a beginner in python. If anyone is interested I am using a Raspberry pi 400 and I am using VSC but anyways here is my code:

```
import turtle
import random

pat=turtle.Turtle()
colours=["orange","blue","red","yellow", "cyan"]
turtle.Screen().bgcolor("black")

for i in range(200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000):
    for i in range(2):
        pat.forward(300)
        pat.right(100)
        pat.right(100)
        pat.forward(300)
        pat.right(100)
        pat.left(5)
        pat.color(random.choice(colours))
```

Comment: Did you call your file `turtle.py`? Also, that loop is probably never going to end in any realistic amount of time. Did you just want an infinite loop?

Comment: In case you want to have an infinite loop, `while True:` is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you have a file named `turtle.py` in the same folder, or in any other folder contained in the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable? In that case `import turtle` might not load the turtle package, but instead the local Python file, which does not contain an executable object named `Turtle` and hence the AttributeError is raised when calling `turtle.Turtle()`.

Comment: Yeah it turns out  i did have another python file called turtle.py